# Error with map relationship Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having trouble creating a solution to this business rule.

I currently have 1 client, 1 correspondent and 1 store. Both use the same address table. As the client, correspondent, and store tables can not have the auto-generated Id, I have decided to use GUIDs to avoid duplicate errors in the Address table. In this case the address table should look like this:

```
AddressId  - ReferenceId          - Street
1          - GuidOfCorrespondent  - St. one
2          - GuidOfStore          - St. two
3          - GuidOfCustomer       - St. three
```

But I'm having trouble mapping entities. Here's the template I'm trying to do:

```
AddressMap() 
{
    HasKey(x => x.AddressId);

    Property(x => x.Street)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(60);

    Property(x => x.Number)
        .IsRequired();

    HasRequired(x => x.Correspondent)
        .WithMany(x => x.Adresses)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.ReferenceId);

    HasRequired(x => x.Customer)
        .WithMany(x => x.Adresses)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.ReferenceId);

    HasRequired(x => x.Store)
        .WithMany(x => x.Adresses)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.ReferenceId);
    }
```

I'm getting this error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.Address_dbo.Customer_ReferenceId\". The conflict occurred in database \"Correspondent\", table \"dbo.Customer\", column 'StoreId'

Can someone help?

Comment: Here is the case. Can you create FK constraint on your `ReferenceId` column in the database? No. Then you cannot map it in EF.

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert all sub entities before inserting the address

Answer (score 0):

If the Correspondent has a navigation property of Address then you can populate the Address at the same time as you populate the Correspondent. Just leave the AddressId on the Correspondent and the AddressId on the Address as zero.

Then when you as enity framework to insert the Correspondent, it will insert the Address record first, then populate the AddressId on the Correspondent before then inserting the Correspondent record.

Comment: I need when add correspondent, the CorrespondentId(Guid) column need include in referenceId(Guid) column of Address.
Am I having a problem with modeling?

Answer (score 0):

You may have inserted customer and addresses the same time in this case  you can simply insert address ,save changes then insert customer you can also make sql to be not sensitive to foreign key constraint and make foreign key column nullabe if you want to insert an entity before it's sub entities